# How to find the desired output using hive/sql

Tags: mysql, sql, hive

I have a table like this

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | a |
| First | b |
| Second | row |
| First | c |
| Second | row |

The output required is like below:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | row | 1 |
| Second | a | 1 |
| First | b | 1 |
| Second | row | 2 |
| First | c | 2 |
| Second | row | 3 |

The logic is , whenever we are getting the value "row" in col2, the col3 will increment the counter, otherwise will skip it.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a column that specifies ordering because SQL tables represent unordered sets.

With such a column, just use conditional aggregation:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when col2 = 'myval' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by <ordering col>) as col3
from t;
```